# create a html file in php by user

Tags: php, html, function, document

well I want to make a feature to my cms which user can make some static page by its orders , such

`file name , Content , picture ....`

for example , user can make an about us.. that file name is about.php , have a custom content in it , and all of these are given by a user in another php page

please recommend me to use which php function to make these , tnx

Comment: It's called a "content management system" when you do this. It's a fairly complex issue. There is no simple answer other than to use an existing system - like Wordpress.

Comment: i want to make easier to who don't know about web-designing , to make a page just by put some information in some inputbox

Comment: and also i want to save the page in server which user make it .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about some code like this:

```
$fh = fopen($filename, 'w') or die("can't open file");
fwrite($fh, '<html><body>');
fwrite($fh, "<h1>$title</h1>$text");
fwrite($fh, '</body></html>');
fclose($fh);
```

where filename, title and text are filled with some form data, or read from a file.

I hope this is what you meant.

Comment: Then read http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.external.php and combine it with what I wrote. I you need anything else, first try the same manual. But I have to warn you that this poses security risks of which some are described here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.variables.php