# Send both html form and the file attahment in PHP

Tags: php, javascript, email

I have been trying to find a way to attach the html form as well as the file attachment through php. The aim is when the user press submit button, both the HTML form (with visible fields only) and the file attachment (uploaded) are attached as email. This is a kind of HTML email but I want the HTML form attached in the email. I am unable to find any solution ?

Comment: How does `[java]` come into the picture?

Comment: Now I need a javascript to save the file and read/open it in php script.

Comment: I see you have the `[javascript]` tag now because java != javascript ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to send the form values as an attachment instead of in the actual body text of the email?  If so, you could create an html page with the data of the form and save it on your server.  Then, send it.  Let me know if you need help and I'll post some code.  I don't recommend this approach very much, however.  You should be sending it in the body text of the email, in my opinion.

Create the file:

```
$fh = fopen($filename, 'w') or die("can't open file");
fwrite($fh, '<html><body>');
fwrite($fh, "<h1>$title</h1>$text");
fwrite($fh, '</body></html>');
fclose($fh);
```

Send the file via php mailer:

```
$mail->AddAttachment($whereEverYouSavedYourFile, $whatEverYourFileNameIs);
```

Try it and post code if it doesn't work (probably a new question with your specific problem).

**Edit:**

To send email with post data, make you form submit to a PHP page with this in it:

```
<?php

// get and sanitize post data like this
// note: you must have a form field with a 'name' of 'firstName' and on of 'lastName'
$firstName = htmlspecialchars($_POST['firstName'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
$lastName = htmlspecialchars($_POST['lastName'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');

// put the data in a new variable
$body = <<<HTML
  First name: $firstName \r\n
  Last name: $lastName \r\n
HTML;

// send mail
mail('whoEver@theirEmailAddress.com', 'form data', $body);

?>
```

Comment: Hi, yes this is not the ideal solution but the requirement is to send a copy of the form. Since, one or more of the fields of the form will also be used to upload file attachments, I have to attach both the HTML form and the files that are to be attached (via form) in a single email.

Comment: Do you need example of what?  To send emails, to create HTML forms, to send multiple attachments?  All three?  I can show you how.

Comment: I know scripts for sending mail, creating html forms but NOT that send an email containing the HTML form itself and the file attachment in a single email.

Comment: You won't be sending the form itself, you will be sending a separate HTML file that you create based on the data submitted in the web form.  Here's how to create an html document in PHP, then just attach the file just as you attach your other attachment http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7180127/create-a-html-file-in-php-by-user.

Comment: I have tried http://www.shotdev.com/php/php-mail/php-send-email-upload-form-attachment-file/ but cannot make it work so not sure if it will work the way I want it or not

Comment: I recommend you use PHPMailer for sending emails with attachments.  You can also use gmail to send via smtp which is a good practice, I think.  Read this http://www.web-development-blog.com/archives/send-e-mail-messages-via-smtp-with-phpmailer-and-gmail/

Comment: I agree that it will not be the same form, rather an HTML copy of the file but it should not reside on server. Perhaps a local copy in temp folder that is then attached with submission. Any clues for the code please.

Comment: Yes, please see the link I already sent (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7180127/create-a-html-file-in-php-by-user).  Just create the file as shown in the link, then you'll save it somewhere, and then just reference where you saved when you go to attach it.

Comment: There you go.  Don't forget to upvote comments that were helpful (i.e. ones including links to tutorials, etc.) as a small way to say thank you.

Comment: It has become very tricky as the form if saved has the folder with css files, so it would perhaps be a zip (containing html+css) of the form. Also struggling with your code as I do not have expertise in php :(

Comment: If you want to send an HTML document with images and styles, you will have to put direct URLs on them so `<img src="/images/myImage.gif" />` becomes `<img src="http://www.myWebsite.com/images/myImage.gif" />`.  Again, you should recommend that you just send the POST data in the body of the email itself, or generate a PDF and send that.  Sending HTML like this is stupid (for lack of better word).

Comment: I have given up. Perhaps I need a way to copy all the form data embed in email and the file attachment (if any) as attachment to that email

Comment: I realize its not feasible so Any code or snippets for. [....you should recommend that you just send the POST data in the body of the email itself, or generate a PDF and send that.]

Comment: Don't give up aus_fas!  I will update my answer with more solutions for you.

Comment: It's updated.  That should help.  Open a new question if you need more help.

Comment: Again, don't forget to accept an answer and upvote comments that were helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Check below link , It will definitely help you.

http://www.finalwebsites.com/forums/topic/php-e-mail-attachment-script

I have used it and it was working for me.

Comment: Hi srbhbarot, what about the form ??

Comment: do you want to send html structure in mail or a html file attached with mail?

Comment: Obviously, the form is HTML (probably a stripped down version). However, the attachment will probably be pdf files.

Comment: ok! So you just need one change in this line : $header .= "Content-type:text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n"; Replace plain by html. And send your html structure in message parameter of mail function.

Comment: There is a php code what about the associated HTML code and where do I have to pu $my_file = "somefile.zip";..... code

Comment: I have given up. Perhaps I need a way to copy all the form data embed in email and the file attachment (if any) as attachment to that email.